# Tomcat + Eclipse + Caching my named queries

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, caching

I have an xml file that I place my named queries like this

```
<named-query name="ConcatenaCep.findByCidadeLogradouroOuBairro">
        <query>
        SELECT new br.gov.consumidor.modelo.ConcatenaCep(c.cep, c.uf, c.localidade, c.bairro, c.logradouro) 
        FROM ConcatenaCep c 
        WHERE c.codigoMunicipio LIKE :codigoMunicipio 
        AND c.bairro LIKE :bairro 
        AND (:logradouro IS NULL OR c.logradouro LIKE :logradouro)
        </query>
</named-query>
```

But when I edit any query inside it and save, re-run mvn clean and install, clean tomcat cache and restart server, my changes don't work, it has no effect.

I exploded the war file that was published into tomcat directory and checked the query there, it is right, like it was supposed to be, but somehow my tomcat is serving the older version of it.

It happened a lot of times already, it starts to work some hours later, sometimes it need a day.

Any ideas how to clean that supposed cache and make it work any time?

Thank you!